# Route specific response compression in dotnet core 2 asp .net?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

This may seem a little pointless, but I want ONE of my API endpoints to support "optimal" gzip compression. For all the others I want either "none" or "fastest".

Is this possible? How can I achieve this?

Optimally I would like to somehow indicate to the service from within the controller action that I would like the current request to be GZipped and what settings to use.

I was thinking I could try to pull the Invoke method from ResponseCompressionMiddleware's and bastardize it into it's own service, but I wanted to see if there was something simpler first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the comments mention using AspNetCore's out-of-the-box support to run `Middleware` as a *Route specific* `Filter` via `MiddlewareFilterAttribute`, but didn't provide an actual implementation...

Here's an elegant way to get it working with only a handful of lines of code using the out-of-the-box Response Compression middleware . . .

In Startup/Program.cs you have to set up the DI for the out-of-the-box Response Compression middleware dependencies:

```cs
builder.Services.AddResponseCompression(options => options.EnableForHttps = true);
```

Then add a new Attribute that encapsulates this so that you're your annotation code at each endpoint is simplified and so it can be enhanced in only one place:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

public class EnableRouteResponseCompressionAttribute : MiddlewareFilterAttribute
{
    public EnableRouteResponseCompressionAttribute () 
        : base(typeof(EnableRouteResponseCompressionAttribute ))
    { }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder) 
        => applicationBuilder.UseResponseCompression();
}
```

And now you can use it simply:

```cs
[Route("get-some-compressed-data")]
[HttpGet]
[EnableRouteResponseCompression] //<== The Magic is Here!
public async Task<Data> GetSomeCompressedData()
{
    // . . . get the data . . . 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so I played around with this for way too long. This answer is to share how I managed to get this to work, but I don't suggest this method and hope someone can point out a really simple way I missed out on.

So without further adieu, the following code worked for my needs:

```cs
class GZipAttribute : ResultFilterAttribute
{
    private class ResponseCompressionOptionsProvider : IOptions<ResponseCompressionOptions>
    {
        private class GZipCompressionProviderOptionsProvider : IOptions<GzipCompressionProviderOptions>
        {
            public GZipCompressionProviderOptionsProvider(CompressionLevel compressionLevel)
            {
                this.Value = new GzipCompressionProviderOptions()
                {
                    Level = compressionLevel
                };
            }
            public GzipCompressionProviderOptions Value { get; private set; }
        }
        public ResponseCompressionOptionsProvider(CompressionLevel level)
        {
            this.Value = new ResponseCompressionOptions()
            {
                EnableForHttps = true
            };
            this.Value.Providers.Add(new GzipCompressionProvider(new GZipCompressionProviderOptionsProvider(level)));
        }
        public ResponseCompressionOptions Value { get; private set; }
    }

    public CompressionLevel CompressionLevel { get; private set; }
    public bool BodyContainsSecret { get; private set; }
    public bool BodyContainsFormInput { get; private set; }

    public GZipAttribute(CompressionLevel compressionLevel, bool bodyContainsSecret = true, bool bodyContainsFormInput = true)
    {
        CompressionLevel = compressionLevel;
    }

    private void logSkippingGzip(ResultExecutingContext ctxt, string reason)
    {
        ILogger logger = ctxt.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ILogger>();
        logger.LogWarning("[GZip] SKIPPED -- " + reason);
    }

    public override async Task OnResultExecutionAsync(ResultExecutingContext executingContext, ResultExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        if (executingContext.HttpContext.Request.IsHttps && BodyContainsFormInput && BodyContainsSecret)
        {
            logSkippingGzip(executingContext, "Request is HTTPS but endpoint is not marked as being impervious to BREACH exploit.");
            await next();
        }
        else
            await new ResponseCompressionMiddleware((context) => { return next(); }, new ResponseCompressionProvider(executingContext.HttpContext.RequestServices, new ResponseCompressionOptionsProvider(CompressionLevel))).Invoke(executingContext.HttpContext);

        return;
    }
}
```

It seems to work swimmingly now but I would like something more concise. Please let me know if you guys/gals have any other ideas. To apply this I simply add  a `[GZip(CompressionLevel.Optimal)]` to any action in my MVC controllers.

Comment: Mvc has a feature where you can add middleware for specific routes/controllers.

Comment: @Tratcher that sounds promising. I'll look into it now.

Comment: So the only way I managed to get it to work with @Tratcher's suggestion would be to explicitly define the route in the MVC call (all my other routes are defined using attributes) and then assign a specific middleware for that route. I don't know if there is another way to define, enable/disable the middleware from within the controller. Ideas?

Comment: I think there is also an attribute for this.

Comment: The middleware filter attribute. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/16/announcing-asp-net-core-1-1/

Comment: @Tratcher: That is really cool. I'll need to play around with this to tweak it so it let's me configure the GZipping as I desire, but I think this will address my needs. If you have time please create an answer with the details and I will accept it. Otherwise I'll update my answer when I figure it all out.

Comment: FYI, for anyone coming here of late, I ust shared a greatly simplified implementation as a separate answer using the out-of-the-box Response Compression Middleware and `MiddlewareFilterAttribute` encapsulated in a simple `EnableRouteResponseCompressionAttribute`

Comment: It does not seem like a good idea to compress the response this early. It will be compressed before it hits any of the exit code of all the middleware filters. Depending on the middleware, this may not be a good thing. I'd counsel against using an ActionAttribute to compress.

Answer (score 0):

Mvc has a feature where you can add middleware for specific routes/controllers.

See the middleware filter attribute here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/16/announcing-asp-net-core-1-1/