# Compress filter at the action level for ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm migrating an ASP.NET MVC 5 application to ASP.NET Core 2.1. In the "old" application I had a Compress filter that was apply Gzip to the response of specific requests. That way I was able to compress only specific requests and not all the requests.

Based on what I understand, ASP.NET Core has a different approach using middlewares and it only gives you the chance to apply compression to all the requests (adding it to the pipeline) or not applying it at all.

Is there a way to achieve what I want by creating an ActionFilterAttribute? this was my old code:

```
public class CompressAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            var acceptEncoding = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(acceptEncoding))
                return;

            acceptEncoding = acceptEncoding.ToLower();
            var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;
            if (acceptEncoding.Contains("gzip"))
            {
                response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
                response.Filter = new GZipStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
            }
            else if (acceptEncoding.Contains("deflate"))
            {
                response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "deflate");
                response.Filter = new DeflateStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Normally with the response compression middleware you enable compression based on MIME type.  If you need more granular control I guess you could strip the Accept-Encoding header in your own middleware.

Comment: Have you managed to create this filter?

Comment: I did not create the filter, I took a different approach. I'm answering my own question below, I hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two different approaches to apply compression to specific scenarios:

1) **Create a middleware** and analyze the request before applying compression. I did not like this approach because the middleware would run for all the requests and would have to examine the request information, affecting the performance.

2) **Modify the Web.config file** (this is the approach I took) and apply compression to certain dynamic and static types. When an ASP.NET Core app is published, a web.config is automatically generated. We can edit the web.config file and add compression like I did in the following example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
    <httpCompression>
      <dynamicTypes>
        <clear />
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="text/*" />
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="message/*" />
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/x-javascript" />
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/javascript" />
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/json" />
        <add enabled="false" mimeType="*/*" />
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/atom+xml" />
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/atom+xml;charset=utf-8" />
      </dynamicTypes>
      <staticTypes>
        <clear />
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="text/*" />
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="message/*" />
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/javascript" />
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/atom+xml" />
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/xaml+xml" />
        <add enabled="false" mimeType="*/*" />
      </staticTypes>
    </httpCompression>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\YourApplicationName.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: An alternative solution with first approach (using ResponseFilter) is answered here.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46124552/6673637

Answer (score 2):

I also had task for compressing responses only for some specific actions/controllers
Finally I've found a solution based on `ActionFilterAttribute`. here is an example

```
namespace CommonWebApi.MiddleWare
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Attribute for enabling Brotli/GZip/Deflate compression for specied action
    /// </summary>
    public class ResponseCompressionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private Stream _originStream = null;
        private MemoryStream _ms = null;

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            HttpRequest request = context.HttpContext.Request;
            string acceptEncoding = request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(acceptEncoding)) return;
            acceptEncoding = acceptEncoding.ToUpperInvariant();
            HttpResponse response = context.HttpContext.Response;
            if (acceptEncoding.Contains("BR", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))//Brotli 
            {
                if (!(response.Body is BrotliStream))// avoid twice compression.
                {
                    _originStream = response.Body;
                    _ms = new MemoryStream();
                    response.Headers.Add("Content-encoding", "br");
                    response.Body = new BrotliStream(_ms, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
                }
            }
            else if (acceptEncoding.Contains("GZIP", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                if (!(response.Body is GZipStream))
                {
                    _originStream = response.Body;
                    _ms = new MemoryStream();
                    response.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
                    response.Body = new GZipStream(_ms, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
                }
            }
            else if (acceptEncoding.Contains("DEFLATE", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                if (!(response.Body is DeflateStream))
                {
                    _originStream = response.Body;
                    _ms = new MemoryStream();
                    response.Headers.Add("Content-encoding", "deflate");
                    response.Body = new DeflateStream(_ms, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
                }
            }
            base.OnActionExecuting(context);
        }

        public override async void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
        {
            if ((_originStream != null) && (_ms != null))
            {
                HttpResponse response = context.HttpContext.Response;
                await response.Body.FlushAsync();
                _ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                response.Headers.ContentLength = _ms.Length;
                await _ms.CopyToAsync(_originStream);
                response.Body.Dispose();
                _ms.Dispose();
                response.Body = _originStream;
            }
            base.OnResultExecuted(context);
        }
    }
}
```

known limitations/essentials:

- MemoryStream is required only to get length of compressed stream. This value should be set to `response.Headers.ContentLength` for correct work.
- currently it works only for 3 types of compression.